# neo4j community edition can have Security control?

Tags: neo4j

Is neo4j community edition  can have security control? if yes, please teach me how to set up security control for neo4j community edition

Many thnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your question is very vague, so is my answer.

Yes, community edition has security features. For details RTFM at http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/security-server.html.